# What is the difference between Inherited and (Inherited + 0)

Tags: stylesheet, style, inheritance

- Let's create a stylesheet:

---

```
NotebookPut@
 Notebook[{
   Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
   Cell[StyleData["myStyle"]], 
   Cell[StyleData["myStyle2", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["myStyle"]]]
}]
```

> [image]

- Now let's add a `FontSize -> 30` spec for our first style and `FontSize ->Inherited` for the last one.

> [image]

- This `FontSize->Inherited` is not necessary, the `FontSize` of `myStyle2` will be 30 anyway, since there is `StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["myStyle"]` ( [**Ref**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14426/5478))

> [image]

- But let's replace `Inherited` with `(Inherited + 0)`:

> [image]

**It immediately changed the size! That means, it inherits from somewhere else now...**

**Q1**: Can this be explained with documentation?

---

Of course `0` makes no sense but **my goal** is to have e.g. `Inherited + 5` so when I change `myStyle` I won't have to change anything in dependent styles.

**Q2**: So I would gladly upvote any answer that will tell me how to achieve this behaviour within one stylesheet.

I tried `FontSize :> (CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "myStyle", FontSize}] + 1)` but to no avail.

---

*key words:* cascading styles style inheritance

---

*loose thoughs*:

I'm afraid it may be tough since e.g. `SubitemParagraph` isn't inheriting `CellMargins` to align with `SubItem` but has it hardcoded to be the same. :-(

One possible solution would be to be able to create `` FrontEnd`CurrentValue["myStyleFontSize"] = 15 `` so that I can set `myStyle` and `myStyle2` `FontSizes` with reference to it like `FontSize :> CurrentValue["myStyleFontSize"]`. There are similar solutions in e.g. Core.nb with `"MenuFontSize"` but it's not the solution *"within one stylesheet"*.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch That's even stranger, on Win7 +Integer gives size of that small size+Integer.

Comment: Have you tried [the TaggingRules method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7754/17)?

Comment: @Silvia no, thanks for the link, I will closely investigate that in a near future :)

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR**: The point of this answer is that we can move styles *merging* from stylesheet to the expression/boxes level. But sill have all definitions kept in the stylesheet.

My last conclusions are that what I was after was not meant to work and an example with plain `Inherited` was a coincidence.

---

We can create *main* styles and *complementary* styles.

So the main is:

```
Cell[StyleData["myStyle"],
 FontSize  -> 35,
 FontColor -> RGBColor[1,0,0]
]
```

And complementary style is e.g. `"biggerFont"`:

```
Cell[
  StyleData["biggerFont"], 
  FontSize -> (Inherited+10)
]
```

The preview of the stylesheet won't be very informative:

> [image]

But we can use it in very useful way:

```
Framed[
 Dynamic@AbsoluteCurrentValue[FontSize],
 BaseStyle -> "myStyle"
 ]

Framed[
 Dynamic@AbsoluteCurrentValue[FontSize],
 BaseStyle -> {"myStyle", "biggerFont"}
 ]
```

> [image]

Neat!

We can combine styles and inheritance will fire at the end.

The order in `{"myStyle", "biggerFont"}` is important.

Answer (score 3):

You may think the following is a cheat, but it accomplishes what you ask for. I tested the code with V10.3 on OS X 10.10.2.

```
With[{size = 24}, 
  CreateDocument[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["myStyle1"], Background -> LightBlue, FontSize -> size], 
    Cell[StyleData["myStyle2", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["myStyle1"]], 
      FontSize -> size + 12]},
    WindowTitle -> "MyStyleSheet"]]
```

[image: stylesheet]

Comment: I think it is good approach to deploy a stylesheet that is not meant to be adjusted by the end-user, which is often the case for me.