# Updating styles which are based on styles changed in private stylesheet

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, style, inheritance

#### Intro

Styles can inherit from other styles: [**base one style on another?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14425/5478)

And for example `WolframAlphaLong` is inheriting from `Input` style.

However, if you modify `Input` in your private stylesheet, this change won't be reflected in `WolframAlphaLong`.

#### Question

What is a generic or fast way to make them respecting those changes?

#### Example

```
CellPrint[Cell["integrate x", "WolframAlphaLong"]]


SetOptions[
   EvaluationNotebook[],
   StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
     Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
     Cell[StyleData["Input"], FontSize -> 25]
   }]
]
```

[image]

As you can see, `"integrate x"` has old font size setting.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case it seems to be inheriting its font characteristics from `TextForm` because of `FormatType->TextForm` in its style definition.

```
CellPrint[Cell["integrate x", "WolframAlphaLong"]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Input"], Black, 12],
    Cell[StyleData["TextForm"], Red, 18]
    }]]
```

[image]

Comment: If you copy `WALong` definition from Default.nb and put at the bottom of your private stylesheet, then WALong will inherit Input changes. It wwould be nice to have that done automatically. `FormatType` is what contributes to the given style too but `TextForm` doesn't have any `FontSize` specs in Default.nb. **The problem is**, I want to change Input and I can't use that method because not every style that Inherits from Input have a `TextForm` `FormatType`, likewise those styles that don't (have Input parent) may have `TextForm` and I don't want them to be updated.

Comment: It is something important here though, your answer shows that while `StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Input"]`-like parents are resolved for each stylesheet for current "styles stack" while `FormatType` inheritance is resolved at the end, at a notebook level probably. Whatever that means :)