# How to disable automatic return in a notebook

Tags: notebooks

When I type in a cell of a notebook Mathematica starts a new line sometimes where I don't want it. Often it is very usefull and it helps to see misplaced brackets and semicolons but normally I would like to disable this feature  to choose my own layout. Is this possible?

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Is [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/DontWordWrap.html) any help?

Comment: Closely related: [(13006)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13006/121)