# How to paste formatted Mathematica code *verbatim* from external text editor to notebook?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, input

In my text editor, *Mathematica* code may look like this:

[image]

YMMV, of course, but *I* at least find this easy to read.

---

If I copy that snippet of code and paste into a *Mathematica* notebook, it looks like this:

[image]

...which I find much harder to read, even for a short code snippet like this one.  For the much longer chunks of code I typically work with, pasting them into a notebook renders them basically unreadable.

**Is there a way to paste pre-formatted code into *Mathematica* verbatim?**

Comment: @Kuba: Thank you!  That's a great trick.  (It deserves to be an Answer.)

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13006/121

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some Mathematica code as it appears after writing it my text editor.

[image: bbedit]

In a Mathematica note book I create a new Code cell with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (in OS X), and paste the code from the text editor into the cell. The gray background indicates the cell has the initialization cell property. Don't want that.

[image: init_cell]

With the mouse cursor in the Code cell (or with the cell selected), hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. The gray background vanishes. The cell no longer has the initialization cell property. It behaves like an input cell except it maintains the plain text formatting.

[image: code_cell]

If you were to copy this code from a Mathematica notebook and paste it into one of this site's editing panes, it would still maintains its line formatting, so all that is needed after pasting is select the code and hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to get the following.

```
foo[x_, y_]:=
  (* This is a comment *)
  Module[{bar = {x, y}, this, that},
    {this, that} = Thread[frob[bar]];
    1 + this/that]
```

#### Update

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> may only work on OS X. The only indication of this keyboard shortcut comes from the Cell menu itself. See bellow

[image: menu]

The `^8` appearing on right side of the indicated menu item is OS X's way of showing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> is available as a shortcut.

Comment: @Kuba. Get a Mac :-)

Comment: @Kuba. It toggles the initialization code property of the cell. Very handy. See my update.

Comment: I like the "Code" style so much, but don't want to answer about "Initialization cells" and whether I want to run them every time I open the notebook.  So I have a custom "NoInitCode" style in my default style sheet

Comment: @JasonB: Can you bind that style to a keyboard shortcut (like Alt+8, etc.)?

Comment: I do, I have it set to Cmd-Shift-8